# How to modify a pyramid template on the fly before rendering

Tags: python-2.7, web-applications, pyramid

please I am working on a site where I would scrap another website's html table source code and append it to my template before rendering my page. 
I have written the script which stores the html code in a variable but don't know how to appendix it.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: What template system are you using?  Chameleon?

Comment: @fatfantasma i am using Chameleon

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jinja, try this:

`<div class="html-content">{{scraped_html|safe}}</div>`

Comment: am using Chameleon template with python but i will attempt your suggestion.

Comment: The solution provided prints {{scraped _ html | safe}} verbertin without putting the html I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the chameleon template system. HTML is the variable that contains your html code that is passed to the template.

```
<div>${structure: HTML}</div>
```

Or I believe this will work also

```
<div tal:content="HTML"></div>
```